# Fetch pl/sql array return values in java

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql

In Java how to get values from a `pl/sql` function which returns an array.

if my pl/sql function returns array called `myArray`, in java is it possible to fetch values 
from `myArray` into java objects using `callablestatement`?

Thanks

Update 1

My Java code where I am calling function, but I am getting exception.

```
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'myfunc'




connection = con.getConnection();
        callablestatement = connection.prepareCall("{call myfunc(?,?,?}");
        callablestatement.setInt(1, param1);
        callablestatement.setInt(2, param2);
        callablestatement.setString(3, param3);
        callablestatement.registerOutParameter(4, Types.ARRAY);
        callablestatement.execute();        
        resultSet = callablestatement.getArray(4).getResultSet();
```

Update 2

```
private final String PRODECURE_NAME = "{? = call myfunc(?,?,?)}";
```

and

```
connection = con.getConnection();
    callablestatement = connection.prepareCall(PRODECURE_NAME);
    callablestatement.registerOutParameter(1, Types.ARRAY);
    callablestatement.setInt(2, param1);
    callablestatement.setInt(3, param2);
    callablestatement.setString(4, param3);

    callablestatement.execute();

create or replace type dates
       is varray(100) of varchar2(32);
```

function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function myfunc (    
    p_id    IN number,
    p_c_id     IN number,
    p_co_no     IN number

)
    RETURN dates
AS
    myarray contract_dates;
    par1        VARCHAR2 (32);
    par2        VARCHAR2 (32);
```

Fixed Update 3

```
connection = con.getConnection();
        callablestatement = 
                connection.prepareCall("begin ? :=myfunc(?,?,?); end;");
        callablestatement.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.ARRAY, "DATES");
        callablestatement.setInt(2, param1);
        callablestatement.setInt(3, param2);
        callablestatement.setString(4, param3);
        callablestatement.execute();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't do that with `ARRAY` but it should works. First you must register `out` parameter of your function. So it can be like this.

```
private final String PRODECURE_NAME = "{? = call <ProcedureName>(?,?,?)}";

Connection con = null;
CallableStatement cs = null;

       try {
            con = DAOFactory.getDatabaseConnection();
            cs = con.prepareCall(PRODECURE_NAME);
            cs.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.ARRAY);
            cs.setYourType(2, <yourData>);
            cs.setYourType(3, <yourData>);
            cs.setYourType(4, <yourData>);
            cs.execute();
            Array arr = cs.getArray(1);
            if (arr != null) {
               String[] data = (String[]) arr.getArray();
            }
        } 
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(OracleLiekDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            try {
                con.rollback();
            }
        }
        finally {
            if (con != null) {
                try {
                    con.close();
                } 
                catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(OracleLiekDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
```

Try this man and give me then asnwer wether it do or not.

**EDIT:**

These char **?** represents one parameter that you will set(it's named as parametrized).
So this:

```
cs.setYourType(2, <yourData>);
cs.setYourType(3, <yourData>);
cs.setYourType(4, <yourData>);
```

means, that you set your three parameters (?), first parameter of method is column index and second are you data of your specific type.

---

**EDIT 2:**

So sorry i wrote bad solution, already updated so check code now and try it.

Comment: I am trying your solution. In my Function I have 3 the in parameters and I would like to make return array as out parameter.  However when I compile  I am getting errors. 
How can I define the function to have in out as 4th paramater? Because in java I am getting exception `wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'myfunc'` Thanks

Comment: First 3 parameters are in params and in java I have written like the following:             `callablestatement.registerOutParameter(4, Types.ARRAY);
            callablestatement.execute();
            
            resultSet = callablestatement.getArray(4).getResultSet();`

Comment: do it like i wrote, out parameter have 1 index not 4, index 2,3,4 are your parameters which have your stored procedure

Comment: `{? = call <ProcedureName>(?,?,?)}` it means that in to first **?** will be selected your `Array`, fist **?** is `OUT` parameter. Now i must go away but i will be back later.

Comment: I have function, not stored procedure. Besides I have included my java code as update 1 above. Thanks

Comment: to to be all clear, you have function but in other words, function is stored procedure that return value of specific type and you right it's usually named like function :-) so then give mi answer wether it works or not.

Comment: I have added my modified code above as update 2. When I execute I am getting exception `java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 13: PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type`

Comment: So yeah man, it was bad solution, i looked at it and corrected code so check it.

Comment: I used your solution, but did a small change. I have added my code as update 3 above. Thanks a lot for your help and support.

Answer (score 1):

myArray returned from PL/SQL is of type **java.sql.Array**. You can invoke **getArray()** on it and type cast it to get **java array**.

```
String[] array = (String[]) myArray.getArray();
```

Comment: Also note that you may need to provide a type map argument: `getArray(typeMap)`. For more information, see [my answer on getArray() and writeArray()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45867910/197733)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to `registerOutParameter` of type `Types.ARRAY`
see example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942203/callablestatement-registeroutparameter-multiple-row-result)

Answer (score 1):

The [JDBC Specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr221/index.html) contains a whole section (16.5) dedicated to dealing with arrays. You might want to give it a look.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use the following method present in the SerialArray class which is a direct descendant of java.sql.Array:

```
Object getArray(Map<String, Class<?>> map)
```

Here the Map is a holder of an object and its property which is to be mapped to the fetched resultset in the returned array.

For more details see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/serial/SerialArray.html  javadoc