# How to access multiple return values in java taken from a sql function

Tags: java, sql, return-value, sql-function

I have java code which should access return values from a SQL function. **SQL function returns four number of values which has VARCHAR type**.
java code is given bellow

```
        ResultSet rs = null;
        CallableStatement stmt = null;
        List<TestObj> objList= new ArrayList<TestObj>();
        try
        {
            stmt = con.prepareCall( "{? = call TEST_FUNCTION(?,?) }");
            int count = 0;
            stmt.registerOutParameter( ++count, Types.VARCHAR );
            stmt.setString( ++count, "A");
            stmt.setString( ++count, "B");
            stmt.execute();
            rs = stmt.getResultSet();
            while( rs.next() )
            {
                TestObj obj= new TestObj ();
                obj.setA( rs.getString( "TEST1" ) );
                obj.setB( rs.getString( "TEST2" ) );
                obj.setC( rs.getString( "TEST3" ) );
                obj.setD( rs.getString( "TEST4" ) );
                objList.add( obj);
            }
        }
        catch( SQLException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
        }
```

When run, it gives me a null point exception at 'rs.next()'. Can anyone **please tell me how to access the return values from the function**.

**Note : Passing values to the function and executing the query works fine without any exceptions ( stmt.execute() run without any exceptions )**

Comment: please tell me how to access to return values

Comment: try while( rs.hasNext() )

Comment: Can you mention the SQL function code..

Comment: It is a 3rd party function. I have no access to the function body. It returns varchar type four parameters

Answer (score 1):

Use the `stmt.getXYZ(column)` methods directly (from [`CallableStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html), e.g. [like this](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-callablestatement-stored-procedure-out-parameter-example/) or this<sup>1</sup>) to access `out` parameters of a stored procedure or result of a function invocation.

For *why* the the NPE exception is generated, see [Statement.getResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getResultSet()):

> [Returns] the current result as a ResultSet object or *null if [..] there are no more results*.

Registered `out` parameters do not count towards any result-set!

---

<sup>1</sup> The posted code should probably look more like the following. I've made some changes [to treat the result as an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10785868/2864740) per "function returns *four [..] values* which [have] VARCHAR type". YMMV.

```
stmt = con.prepareCall( "{ ? = call TEST_FUNCTION(?,?) }");
// Specify that an array is expected.
stmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.ARRAY);
stmt.setString(2, "A");
stmt.setString(3, "B");
stmt.execute();

// Access the out parameter/result.
Array arr = stmt.getArray(1);
String[] data = (String[]) arr.getArray();
// Do stuff - no check for if arr is non-null because if it's null then
// an Exception is likely an "appropriate" reaction. Adapt as required.

// And do not use stmt.getResultSet() because none was returned.
```