# How can we pass array to IN param and retrieve array from OUT param using java sql

Tags: java, sql, arrays, plsql

Pass array to `IN` param and getting array from `OUT` param using java sql .
Without using `ArrayDescriptor` class.

I had a stored procedure like

```
create or replace Proc_name(
    vargs IN paramarray1,
    resp  OUT paramarray2)
..............
......
```

vargs like 5 input values and res will be in 3 out parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a java.sql.CallableStatement around your stored procedure, and then use the setArray and getArray methods.

Here's an example:
[Fetch pl/sql array return values in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10785459/fetch-pl-sql-array-return-values-in-java)

Comment: How to setArray without using ArrayDescriptor class